# Chrome crashes when using reCaptcha in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, recaptcha

I've encountered an issue where using reCaptcha in Internet Explorer causes a Java popup, sometimes repeatedly.  This leads to Google Chrome becoming unresponsive, even though it's not running.

I haven't been able to find anything related to this issue, unless my Google-fu is letting me down.

The concern is that this will cause issues with user experience.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so what was your fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Internet Explorer has a new security feature, called ActiveX control blocking, to keep ActiveX controls, such as Java, up-to-date. This feature will prevent the app or web page from loading.

To fix this, just [download Java](https://www.java.com/en/) on your computer again. You need to have the latest Java version or higher in order for it to work on IE 9 and higher.

> Click on the Free Java Download button, and on the download page, click Agree and Start Free Java Download. If you've already installed the version, you will see a message, "This software has already been installed on your computer. Would you like to reinstall it?" Click Yes and reinstall Java.

Hope this works for you!